# How to crop image canvas/mask when hover?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Any react library or quick CSS way to crop the image's canvas when on hover?

Like this: https://imgur.com/A4x0DJ7.gif

Thank you

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple `clip-path` can do it:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: grey;
}

img {
  display: block;
  clip-path: inset(0);
  transition: .5s all;
}

.box:hover img {
  clip-path: inset(10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1069/200/200">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go;

I just used the divs instead of images which i hope is ok.

```css
#img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#image {
height: 280px;
width: 280px;
background-color: orange;
}

#image:hover {
  transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  width: 260px;
  height: 260px;
}
```

```html
<div id='img'>
  <div id='image'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Comment down if you need explanation .

Comment: Changing `width` and `height` is not the same as cropping.

Comment: I think padding is also an option. first set some padding and then remove it on hover